# reboot won't work after rom flash

Tags: rooting, twrp, android-11, magisk, realme

I successfully flashed a pre-rooted stock rom (C.17) using SP Flash Tool on my Realme 6 but after that, reboot won't work. When I tried to reboot (using power button or adb) it just shuts down so I had to turn it on manually, so rebooting is turn it off then on manually. Everything works but reboot. I have TWRP 3.6 and Magisk 24.3.

Comment: If I am not wrong the C.17 and Realms 6 are two different ohones. Flashing a ROM developed for a different phone is a bad idea as it will not work and has just the chance to brick your phone. Android ROMs do only work on phones that have 100% the same hardware, not the same hardware specs, really identical hardware!

Comment: What i meant is flashing the update rmx2001_c.17